# Reformatting multiple columns and rows of data into a single row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have data across four columns where every two cells is related. In other words, every 4x2 block of cells. In the below, every letter is in it's own cell. I've been playing with INDEX and OFFSET formulas to attempt to solve this, but haven't had any luck. The entire set of data is over 1000 rows.

Current format:

[image]

Desired format:

[image]

Comment: The quickest way to do this would be copy the four columns and paste alongside your existing data. Delete the top row from the newly pasted columns. In Column I put a 1 alongside the data in Row 1 and a 2 in Row 2. Auto fill the 1 and 2 on alternating rows to the bottom of your data. Sort all 9 columns by Col I. Delete all rows with a 2 in Col I. Delete Col I.

Comment: Thanks, it isn't sexy, but it works!

Comment: It scares me when people create complex fixes to simple problems. It's part of the reason most people think using Excel is one of the dark arts.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hacky way but only takes a few seconds. The gray columns below represent your original data. I added column A for "keep". Alternate Y/blank, which can be accomplished with a formula or manually done.

Then in cell F2, input this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK($A2),"",B3)
```

Drag is across and down.

Finally, copy columns A:I and paste as special text elsewhere (to remove the formulas). Then sort by keep and delete the blanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to copy the rows to a new workbook.

- In the fifth column of the first data row add the formula
  `=MOD(ROW(),2)` or `=MOD(ROW();2)`
  (whichever works for your version).
  I found out that for this to work, the first row must contain
  only headers, so you should add the formula to the fifth cell
  of the second row (which is the first data row).
- Click the formula and extend it by dragging down to all the rows
- Select the column with the formulas and click *Data > Filter*
  in the banner
- Filter on the value of `0` so only even rows are shown
- Select all the displayed data and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Go to the new workbook, position to the first cell and click
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- Return to the old workbook and filter on `1` so only odd rows are shown
- Select all the displayed data and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Go to the new workbook, position to the fifth cell on the first row
  and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
- Done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `SEQUENCE` function (Office 365, Excel Online), you can do this with a single formula.

I assumed the 4x2 that you mentioned, and you can add pairs of rows to the original table; the formula should adjust to that.

I **Name**'d the data range `myRng`, but you can use regular addressing if you prefer.

Enter this formula into some cell, and the results will `SPILL` to the surrounding region.

```
H1: =INDEX(myRng,INT(SEQUENCE(,8,0,1)/4)+SEQUENCE(ROWS(myRng)/2,,1,2),MOD(SEQUENCE(,4*2,0,1),4)+1)
```

[image]

The `rows` argument for the `INDEX` function returns a 2D array:

```
=INT(SEQUENCE(,8,0,1)/4)+SEQUENCE(ROWS(myRng)/2,,1,2) =>
```

[image]

The `columns` argument also returns an array:

```
=MOD(SEQUENCE(,4*2,0,1),4)+1
```

[image]

When those arrays are used for the rows and columns arguments, the results are as you see in the screenshot above.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365, here is a general reshaper (without reordering):

```
=LET( Matrix, A1:D6,
      newRows, 3,
      newCols, 8,
       rM, ROWS( Matrix ),
       cM, COLUMNS( Matrix ),
       cells, rM * cM,
       reshapedRows, IF( newRows > 0, newRows,
                         IF( newCols > 0, ROUNDUP( cells/newCols, 0), rM ) ),
       reshapedCols, IF( newCols = 0, ROUNDUP( cells/reshapedRows, 0), newCols ),
       RC, SEQUENCE( reshapedRows, reshapedCols, 0 ),
       negRC, SEQUENCE( reshapedRows, reshapedCols, cells-1, -1 ),
       INDEX( Matrix, INT( RC/cM ) + 1, MOD( RC, cM ) + 1 )   )
```

Where it has A1:D6, put in your original array (range, matrix...).  I called that variable **Matrix**.  To tell it what you want the new shape to be, put in numbers (or a cell address, e.g. E1) into **newRows** and/or **newCols**.  I put in 3 and 8 to match your image.  You can leave either **newRows** or **newCols** blank and it will compute the missing parameter.

Here is an example:

[image: 3X8]

And another:

[image: 4X6]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:
`=INDEX($A:$H,INT(((ROW(A1)-1)*8+COLUMN(A1)-1)/4)+1,MOD((ROW(A1)-1)*8+COLUMN(A1)-1,4)+1)`

[image]